# Update trigger inserts a new record but the insert trigger will not fire

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, triggers

SQL Server 2005 or 2008:
I have an UPDATE trigger that will insert a new record into the same table only if a certain status field is changed.

The new record does get created properly so the UPDATE trigger works.  But the INSERT trigger will not fire when the record is created in this way.

When I pull the insert statement from the trigger and run it separately, the INSERT trigger does fire and executes correctly as it also does when a record is created from a form.

Therefore both triggers do work as designed.  I set recursion on for a test but that did not work.  So I guess the simple question is...can this be done?

Comment: Put the code to look for errors, and explain more, its confusing

Comment: It can be done. Triggers can be nested up to a Maximum of 32 levels. As Ann suggested, put the code up .. it will give us an idea of what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn on Nested Triggers for your server.  Here's how:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE ;
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'nested triggers', 1 ;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Be aware that this affects *all* databases, and can have unintended consequences (for triggers that were not intended to cascade like this).

Comment: Since this is required only when a certain condition is met, is it possible to tun on nested triggers in the update trigger and then turn them off in the insert>

Comment: @Dave It's not advisable (and maybe not even possible) to do something like this within an interactive transaction.  You should regard it as an all or nothing deal.  However, you should first check to see if it's already on or not (it usually is).

Comment: Just tested your solution and it works perfectly.  This is a dedicated server so it should be no problem to do this and this is a safe scenario.  Many thanks again...!